# Терминал VSCode не видит venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, powershell

[image]

Помогите, не могу найти решение данной проблемы: Среда Python virtual успешно активирована, хотя индикатор "(.venv)" может отсутствовать в запросе терминала. Подробнее.

Comment: [Попробуй](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993198/venv-indicator-may-not-be-present-in-the-terminal-prompt)